# Mediacontroller behind navigation bar

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tk.ejb1123.quickflix.VideoPayer"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:id="@+id/layoutf">


<VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {

        View decorView;
        decorView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                       // | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        );}
}
```

link to the images example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEhU5.jpg

[image]

I tried changing the gravity and it does not seem to work, and I could not find anything on the internet to fix this issue. The mediaContoller is anchored to R.id.videoView. I don't know how this works in other apps like play books.

Comment: I had a related issue also - but I was using a scrollview as the root container instead, so doing mediaController.setAnchorView(scrollView); worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently, I didn't find any good way to solve it, but that workaround :

First get the navigation_bar_height :

```
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    mNavigationBarSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(resourceId), resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Then, you can add a listener to your mediaController, something like that (mRelativeLayout is the parent of my videoview) :

```
mMediaController.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
        ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = mNavigationBarSize;
        mRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
        hideSystemUI();
        ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = 0;
        mRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

I hope it will help you

Edit : if your activity have a "white theme", you'll see a little graphical glitch when switching, you may have to add : `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` in the theme of this activity (or do it programmaticly)

Comment: Dies google have documentation on how they do it in there apps or example code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by setting Gravity and Margins.

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, on OnCreate() set MediaController layout and assign the same using setLayoutParams().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_video);

    ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(100,0,0,0));
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Big Bunny");

    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

    dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    lpp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dm.widthPixels, 170);
    lpp.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;
    lpp.setMargins(0,0,0,100);
    video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    video.setVideoPath("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    video.setMediaController(mediaController = new MediaController(this){
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    ((Activity) getContext()).onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });
    hideSystemUI();
    mediaController.setLayoutParams(lpp);
    mediaController.setAlpha(0.5f);
    video.start();
    video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    video.setOnInfoListener(this);
}
```

If you want, you can also handle orientation changes using below code.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        lpp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dm.widthPixels, 170);
        //lpp.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;
        //lpp.setMargins(0,0,0,100);
        mediaController.setLayoutParams(lpp);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Landscape",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        lpp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(dm.widthPixels, 170);
        lpp.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;
        lpp.setMargins(0,0,0,100);
        mediaController.setLayoutParams(lpp);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Portrait",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```